# Two ISR with the same timer AVR

Tags: timer, interrupt, avr

I'd like to know if it's possible to use 2 different ISR (e.g. ICP input capture and timer overflow) in AVR microcontrollers

Comment: Yes it's possible! What're the interrupts you have to use?

Comment: Input capture and timer overflow

Comment: What's the micro? The manual of the 328p says: "When a capture is triggered, the 16-bit value of the counter (TCNT1) is written to the Input Capture Register (ICR1). The Input Capture Flag (ICF1) is set at the same system clock as the TCNT1 value is copied into ICR1 register.". Then it seems nothing of that should affect the TOV ISR or TCNT1 register. In each case all the interrupt are completely independent because each interrupt has its vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Each independent interrupt source has its own vector.